# Installing MySQL workbench on CentOS

Tags: mysql-workbench

Using

```
sudo yum install mysql-workbench-community-6.1.7-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
```

Getting the following:

`Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.nbrc.ac.in
 * extras: mirror.nbrc.ac.in
 * updates: mirror.nbrc.ac.in
Setting up Install Process
Examining mysql-workbench-community-6.1.7-1.el6.x86_64.rpm: mysql-workbench-community-6.1.7-1.el6.x86_64
Marking mysql-workbench-community-6.1.7-1.el6.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mysql-workbench-community.x86_64 0:6.1.7-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: python-paramiko for package: mysql-workbench-community-6.1.7-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libatkmm-1.6.so.1()(64bit) for package: mysql-workbench-community-6.1.7-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libcairomm-1.0.so.1()(64bit) for package: mysql-workbench-community-6.1.7-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libgdkmm-2.4.so.1()(64bit) for package: mysql-workbench-community-6.1.7-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libgiomm-2.4.so.1()(64bit) for package: mysql-workbench-community-6.1.7-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libglibmm-2.4.so.1()(64bit) for package: mysql-workbench-community-6.1.7-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libgtkmm-2.4.so.1()(64bit) for package: mysql-workbench-community-6.1.7-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libpangomm-1.4.so.1()(64bit) for package: mysql-workbench-community-6.1.7-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libsigc-2.0.so.0()(64bit) for package: mysql-workbench-community-6.1.7-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libtinyxml.so.0()(64bit) for package: mysql-workbench-community-6.1.7-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libzip.so.1()(64bit) for package: mysql-workbench-community-6.1.7-1.el6.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package cairomm.x86_64 0:1.8.0-2.1.el6 will be installed
---> Package glibmm24.x86_64 0:2.22.1-1.el6 will be installed
---> Package gtkmm24.x86_64 0:2.18.2-1.el6 will be installed
---> Package libsigc++20.x86_64 0:2.2.4.2-1.el6 will be installed
---> Package libzip.x86_64 0:0.9-3.1.el6 will be installed
---> Package mysql-workbench-community.x86_64 0:6.1.7-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libtinyxml.so.0()(64bit) for package: mysql-workbench-community-6.1.7-1.el6.x86_64
---> Package pangomm.x86_64 0:2.26.0-1.el6 will be installed
---> Package python-paramiko.noarch 0:1.7.5-2.1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: python-crypto >= 1.9 for package: python-paramiko-1.7.5-2.1.el6.noarch
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mysql-workbench-community.x86_64 0:6.1.7-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libtinyxml.so.0()(64bit) for package: mysql-workbench-community-6.1.7-1.el6.x86_64
---> Package python-crypto.x86_64 0:2.0.1-22.el6 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: mysql-workbench-community-6.1.7-1.el6.x86_64 (/mysql-workbench-community-6.1.7-1.el6.x86_64)
           Requires: libtinyxml.so.0()(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest`

Comment: have you tried adding the requirement it states?

Comment: Yes, I did both of them, but it still failed.

Comment: Did you try installing libtinyxml?

Comment: No, what is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was running into the same issue, and I wasn't able to find libtinyxml in YUM. I found a location where you could download the file though. <strike>http://pkgs.org/altlinux-sisyphus/classic-x86_64/tinyxml-2.6.1-alt1.x86_64.rpm.html</strike>. Dead link 2016-03-30.

This is the command I ran:

```
yum install http://ftp.altlinux.org/pub/distributions/ALTLinux/Sisyphus/x86_64/RPMS.classic/tinyxml-2.6.1-alt1.x86_64.rpm
```

Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
yum install epel-release
yum install tinyxml
yum install mysql-workbench-community
```

Comment: Worked perfectly on CentOs 7.

Answer (score 1):

You can get libtinyxml here:
http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/23719120/dir/centos_6/com/tinyxml-2.6.1-1.3.i686.rpm.html

I've the same problem, on CentOS 6.6 32bits, and can install MySQLWorkbench after install this package with libtinyxml.

Answer (score 0):

To install MySQL-workbench on Centos 7 and similar Linux OS like RHEL.
The following is what worked for me on Centos 7 (it will probably apply to similar os too)

1. First download the MySQL-workbench matching your os-version from here
   [Download site](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/) (this is the RPM file etc)
2. Run the following to install the Mysql-workbench from the file you just downloaded. This is given in the RPM install section of the docs (replacing the bold below with your downloaded file)

   sudo rpm -Uvh ***mysql-community-release-el7-7.noarch.rpm***

After the above command is run, you may run into missing dependencies issues which you can solve by searching for the missing dependency and installing it. 
For example to install a missing *libGLU*

```
sudo yum search libGLU
sudo yum install libGLU
```

Docs link for the #2 link above (see Using the Yum Package Manager)  [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-installing-linux.html#wb-installing-linux-requirements).

Finally, to launch it after install is done, you can type "mysql-workbench" from the command line.

Answer (score -1):

I had no trouble installing the 32 bit version of mysql workbench this way onto my 32 bit Centos 6 system (by the way, the link posted in the first answer no longer seems to work):

## yum install mysql-workbench-community-6.1.7-1.el6.i686.rpm

Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.clarkson.edu
 * epel: mirror.sfo12.us.leaseweb.net
 * extras: mirrors.kernel.org
 * updates: mirrors.syringanetworks.net
Setting up Install Process
Examining mysql-workbench-community-6.1.7-1.el6.i686.rpm: mysql-workbench-community-6.1.7-1.el6.i686
Marking mysql-workbench-community-6.1.7-1.el6.i686.rpm to be installed
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mysql-workbench-community.i686 0:6.1.7-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libtinyxml.so.0 for package: mysql-workbench-community-6.1.7-1.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libzip.so.1 for package: mysql-workbench-community-6.1.7-1.el6.i686
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libzip.i686 0:0.9-3.1.el6 will be installed
---> Package tinyxml.i686 0:2.6.1-1.el6 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

============================================================================================================

## Package                      Arch    Version          Repository                                      Size

Installing:
 mysql-workbench-community    i686    6.1.7-1.el6      /mysql-workbench-community-6.1.7-1.el6.i686    113 M
Installing for dependencies:
 libzip                       i686    0.9-3.1.el6      base                                            38 k
 tinyxml                      i686    2.6.1-1.el6      epel                                            47 k

## Transaction Summary

Install       3 Package(s)

Total size: 113 M
Total download size: 85 k
Installed size: 113 M
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading Packages:
(1/2): libzip-0.9-3.1.el6.i686.rpm                                                   |  38 kB     00:00

### (2/2): tinyxml-2.6.1-1.el6.i686.rpm                                                  |  47 kB     00:00

Total                                                                        76 kB/s |  85 kB     00:01
Running rpm_check_debug
Running Transaction Test
Transaction Test Succeeded
Running Transaction
  Installing : libzip-0.9-3.1.el6.i686                                                                  1/3 
  Installing : tinyxml-2.6.1-1.el6.i686                                                                 2/3 
  Installing : mysql-workbench-community-6.1.7-1.el6.i686                                               3/3 
  Verifying  : tinyxml-2.6.1-1.el6.i686                                                                 1/3 
  Verifying  : mysql-workbench-community-6.1.7-1.el6.i686                                               2/3 
  Verifying  : libzip-0.9-3.1.el6.i686                                                                  3/3

Installed:
  mysql-workbench-community.i686 0:6.1.7-1.el6

Dependency Installed:
  libzip.i686 0:0.9-3.1.el6                            tinyxml.i686 0:2.6.1-1.el6

Complete!